# Salesforce Live Agent chat button not appearing after switching users with Live Agent feature license

Tags: liveagent

The `Chat to Agent` button is not appearing on our website.

It was working fine, then I changed the users who had the `Live Agent` feature license and also added them to the Permission Set; and now the button will not appear.

**Live Agent Configuration**

1. Live Agent Permission Set:

   - Full access to object: `Live Chat Transcripts`
   - Full access to object: `Live Chat Visitors`
   - Full access to object: `Live Agent Sessions`
   - Service Presence Statuses Access: `Available - Live Agent` is selected
2. Live Agent Chat Button

   - Routing Type: `Omni-Channel Queues`
   - Is configured to use the `Live Agent Queue`
3. Live Agent Configurations

   - Has the users assigned
4. Users configuration

   - `Live Agent` Feature license ticked
   - `Service Cloud User` Feature license ticked
5. Omni-Channel Settings

   - `Enable Omni-Channel` is ticked
   - `Enable Skills-Based Routing` is **not** ticked
6. Default Presence Configuration

   - Capacity of `2`
7. Presence Statuses

   - has a presense of `Available - Live Agent` which has `Live Agent` as the selected channel
8. Routing Configurations

   - has a `Live Agent Routing Config` which is configured to use queue `Live Agent Queue`
   - `Routing Priority` of `1`
   - `Routing Model` of `Most Available`
   - `Units of Capacity` of `1.00`
9. Live Agent Queue

   - has the correct users selected.
10. Live Agent Settings

    - `Enable Live Agent` is ticked
11. Live Agent Skills

    - There is a skill and the two users have been added to the skill.
    - NOTE: We are not using Skills.

**QUESTION**

1. Why won't the chat button appear?
2. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration must be fine because the following day Live Agent started to work again.

I suspect user error... i.e. they weren't logged in, when they said they were.